# wickedpdf not rendering images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, wicked-pdf

i am using `wickedpdf` gem to generate `pdf` `invoice` from the `html` code.

gems:

```
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem "wkhtmltopdf-binary"
```

gemfile.lock

```
wicked_pdf (1.0.6)
wkhtmltopdf-binary (0.9.9.3)
```

in controller:

```
  def show_pdf_invoice
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :layout => "pdf.pdf.erb" }
      format.pdf do
    render pdf: "show_pdf_invoice", :layout => 'pdf.pdf.erb'
    #render :pdf => "pdf"#, :layout => 'pdf.html.erb'
      end
    end
  end
```

in `views/invoices/show_pdf_invoice.pdf.erb`

```
  <img id="image" src="https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2016/holidays-2016-day-2-6356741311692800-scta.png" alt="logo" /> 
  <%= wicked_pdf_image_tag 'https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2016/holidays-2016-day-2-6356741311692800-scta.png' %>
```

`pdf` is getting generated. But the images are not showing. in the place of  images empty boxes are coming. unable to find the issue.

Comment: I've had the same problem, mine was fixed by removing `https` for `http`. Have you tried this?

Comment: its working. after changing https to http. but how can i fix this issue for the dynamic images which comes from amazon s3?

Comment: You could use `gsub` for that as in: `gsub("https", "http")`

Comment: add it as a Answer.

Comment: Glad to help you, and have a merry xmas =)

Comment: Thanks a lot. wish you the same.

Comment: @John Oh wow, that's a really old version of `wkhtmltopdf` provided by `wkhtmltopdf-binary`. I'd suggest you try a newer release and maybe you won't have to replace https with http; but beware, you should give your rendered pdfs a visual check since so much with that project has changed in the past few years.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've had the same problem, mine was fixed by removing `https` for `http`. Have you tried this? and for the Amazon S3 part: You could use `gsub` for that as in: `gsub("https", "http")`

Answer (score 3):

Using Rails 5.2 with Active Storage in combination with Amazon S3 storage I had the same problem. 
In development on my local machine the images rendered perfectly, but on Heroku 
they were presented as small empty rectangles.

To get the url from the logo uploaded to Active Storage I used: `@my_object.logo.service_url`.
Which used the standard url with `https`. As mentioned before, replacing this with `http` resolved the issue.

Full code used in my pdf generator view:

```
<%= wicked_pdf_image_tag @my_object.logo.service_url.gsub("https", "http") %>
```

Answer (score 3):

### Two Options

#### 1. Upgrade to `wkhtmltopdf 0.12.5`.

*-or-*

#### 2. Install `libssl1.0-dev` with `apt-get install libssl1.0-dev`.

See this issue for more information: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3001

Comment: Thanks a lot! After upgrading to 0.12.5 it starts to render images (https as well)